# Transform pandas groupby / aggregate result to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, matrix, dataframe, series

After grouping and aggregating data using:

```
byExpImp = data.groupby(['Exporter', 'Importer','sitc4'])
result = byExpImp['Value'].aggregate(np.sum)
```

I'm get a result similar as follow:

```
Exporter     Importer  sitc4

Afghanistan  World     11           59.0
                       12          892.0
                       113          19.0
Austria      World     11           41.0
                       113           8.0
                       118           4.0

Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

Since the results are Series and not dataframe, I can't transform it into a dataframe that looks like this:

```
                11         12       113       118     . 

Afghanistan    59.0     892.0      19.0         0     .
Austria        41.0         0       8.0       4.0     .  
   .              .         .         .         .     .      
   .              .         .         .         .     .
```

Can anybody guide me how to achieve this? Tks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

assuming you have the following Pandas.Series:

```
In [227]: result
Out[227]:
Exporter     Importer  sitc4
Afghanistan  World     11        59.0
                       12       892.0
                       113       19.0
Austria      World     11        41.0
                       113        8.0
                       118        4.0
Name: val, dtype: float64
```

you can pivot it as follows:

```
In [228]: (result.reset_index(name='Value')
     ...:        .pivot_table(index='Exporter', columns='sitc4', values='Value',
     ...:                     aggfunc='sum', fill_value=0)
     ...: )
     ...:
Out[228]:
sitc4        11   12   113  118
Exporter
Afghanistan   59  892   19    0
Austria       41    0    8    4
```

Answer (score 3):

This will give you the dataframe

```
result = data.groupby(['Exporter', 'Importer','sitc4']).Value.sum().reset_index()
```

EDIT:

You can convert the dataframe to matrix using

```
result.as_matrix()
```

Comment: Great stuff, tks! And do you have any idea how can I transform the resulting dataframe into a matrix (as the example)?

Comment: result.as_matrix()

Answer (score 0):

After getting the results as a dataframe (answer given by A-Za-z), you just need this code:

```
result.pivot(index='Exporter', columns='sitc4', values='Value')
```